# Exporting list of lists in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

[image: list of list]

I have a list of lists (you can see on the pic), and would like to export it as .csv. I tried to convert it into feature collection, and then run the following lines:

```
var feature = ee.Feature(null, lossperyearperelevation1);
var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection([feature]);
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: featureCollection,
  description: 'exportTableExample',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'});
```

it gives the following error: *Error: Feature, argument 'metadata': Invalid type. Expected type: Dictionary. Actual type: List<List<Dictionary>>.*

I am confused if it is a list of list, and how to export it in .csv. How can I solve this problem?

the link for the sample code is here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/40c2c24233a6119ee577fb05dd86a14e

Comment: The error you're receiving part of "converting it into feature collection", not from the `Export` operation. We need more information — could you please [edit] your question to include the "converting" code, and preferably a sample list of lists of dictionaries to run it on? Also, what shape of CSV output are you hoping to get? An example CSV file written out would help.

Comment: Hey @KevinReid I added *Export* code and the link to my question. Well, I do not exatly know what shape of CSV i want. I just need to export all the data in a way that I can see the loss per year in different elevations. I am not sure if it is feasible, but I am open to any suggestion!

Comment: The error is at line 57 with the 

var feature = ee.Feature(null, lossperyearperelevation1);
var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection([feature]);

Comment: @UdithaHerath do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grouped reducer output are always a bit messy. Here is a way to rework your output to a feature collection:

```
// rework output
var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(lossperyearperelevation1.map(function(element){
  element = ee.Dictionary(element); // cast
  var list = ee.List(element.get('groups'));
  var feats = ee.FeatureCollection(list.map(function(listEl){
    var dict = ee.Dictionary(listEl);
    return ee.Feature(null, dict);
  }));
  return feats
})).flatten();
```

As there are not so many comments in your code, it is hard to understand what your goal is. [Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/73e207c885ccf935b36991c15ffb8bc9)

Comment: how can I learn the logic behind this code? I would like to understand how to convert different data types to a feature collection in GEE. I will need to use this in the coming part of my study. Do you have any suggestions for me regarding that? Any document, and webpage...?